# How can I hide 'all' when using data filter?

Tags: jquery

I've coded up a data filter for a basic search for shops. here is my code

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 wow animated fadeInUp">
                    <ul class="portfolio-filters text-center">
                        <li class="filter active" data-filter=".fave">Featured</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".design">arts & Crafts</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".html">Garden</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".wordpress">Gifts & Experiences</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Hair & Beauty</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Home</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".cloth">Clothing</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Office & Stationary</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Parenting & Children</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".sports">Sports & Fitness</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Tech & Gadgets</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".music">Music & Recreation</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".toys">Toys</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Travel</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Well-being</li>
                    </ul><!--.portfolio-filter nav-->

                    <div id="portfolio_list" class="row">
```

Is there anyway that the items that don't feature "fave" can be hidden from the main selection?

Here is the site I'm using it for, click shopping and you'll see what I mean Skate Hut shouldn't be visible as it doesn't have the 'fave' data filter

http://www.thatcreativething.com//shopper/index.html

Comment: Is your setting of the active class accurate? If so, it's just a CSS issue

Comment: Honestly I'm no sure. I'm using a template and have very basic HTML knowledge, looking at the CSS I can't see anything that suggests anything

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 wow animated fadeInUp">
    <ul class="portfolio-filters text-center">
        <li class="filter active" data-filter=".fave">Featured</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".design">arts & Crafts</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".html">Garden</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".wordpress">Gifts & Experiences</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Hair & Beauty</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Home</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".cloth">Clothing</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Office & Stationary</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Parenting & Children</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".sports">Sports & Fitness</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Tech & Gadgets</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".music">Music & Recreation</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".toys">Toys</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Travel</li>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".seo">Well-being</li>
    </ul>
    <!--.portfolio-filter nav--> 
</div>
</div>
<button id="filter">Click</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", "#filter", function() {
  $("li.filter").each( function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-filter") !== ".fave") {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i prefer `$(this).hide();`, slightly shorter and does the same as `$(this).css("display", "none");`

Comment: Where does this need to go?  boy I'm so lost.  I notice you've put in an extra   bit of code <button id="filter">Click</button> what is that for?

Comment: The button is just to trigger the functionality. I created a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/eeLw57bp/

Comment: Ahh Ok thank you. But, were would I need to put the Jqueary code? Can I create a new JS document or does it need to go someplace particular?

Comment: You can put it into a separate JS file and include it into your document

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I think I may have done it wrong but its not working. http://thatcreativething.com//shopper/index.html

Comment: Figured it out, it was so simple there was a flter:'*', in the java script, just changed the * with  my preferred filter an all works fine. Thanks for all your help.